# How to execute a statement only after completion of forEach loop in async code

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

```
app.post('/tournament-selected', async (req, res) => {
const { tournamentSelectedId } = req.body;
const tournamentApiUrl = `https://cricheroes.in/api/v1/tournament/get-tournament-detail/${tournamentSelectedId}`;
const apiResponse = await fetch(tournamentApiUrl, { method: 'GET', headers: headers });
const data = await apiResponse.json();
let teamsInfo = [];
data.data.teams.forEach((team, index) => {
    teamsInfo[index] = {
        teamName: team.team_name,
        teamId: team.team_id
    }
});
let i = 0;
let tournamentPlayers = [];

teamsInfo.forEach(async team => {
    const playersApiUrl = `https://cricheroes.in/api/v1/team/get-team-member/${team.teamId}?`;
    const apiResponse = await fetch(playersApiUrl, { method: 'GET', headers: headers });
    const data = await apiResponse.json(); //this data contains team memebers
    data.data.members.forEach((player) => {
        tournamentPlayers[i] = {
            playerName: player.name,
            playerId: player.player_id,
            teamName: team.teamName
        }
        i++;
    })

})

res.send(tournamentPlayers);
```

})
I want to execute the last statement only after the execution of outer forEach loop (teamInfo.forEach). How can we achieve this?

Comment: Would it doable to move the res.send call just after  the `data.data.members.forEach` statement ?

Comment: @AntonioPantano No, It would not send the desired data. Also, It would give error of setting header after the request was sent.